# How can I upgrade an ancient Win 2000 based domain controller to Windows 2008/2012? (by replacement)

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

We're running Windows 2000 as our domain controller (!) and a separate backup domain controller, but as the PDC is 12 years old we would like to replace it. We have a couple of 2008 R2 and Win 2012 (virtual) servers in the office used for other functions which we would like to use as the PDC/BDC.

Is there a way to migrate the domain controller function from the Win 2000 server to the Win 2012 server or would we have to go via 2003 or 2008?  Is it a simple matter of adding the new servers to the domain and somehow promoting them to be the primary domain controller or is it more complicated?  Overall it's a small network with around 12 computers. Unfortunately I wasn't the one to set up the network in the first place so I'm not totally familiar with domains and Active Directory etc.   Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a Windows 2012 DC is not supported in a Windows 2000 Domain, you need to go through Windows 2003/2008/2008 R2 first. (The forest/domain functional level needs to be 2003)

So you would:

- Install a 2003/2008/2008 R2 DC
- Switch all Roles there
- Decommission the 2000 DC
- Raise functional level
- Do the same with 2012/2012R2

Comment: Thanks - what do you mean by "raise functional level" - do you mean promote to DC?

Comment: No, a Domain/Forest has different functional levels, which specifies the features that are available. I could google it for you, but I hope you can do it yourself :)